# Pass parameter to subroutines from another module perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to do something like this: There are:

```
package Module;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(print);

sub print {
    my $nr = shift;
    print "$nr\n";
    if ($nr >= 5) {
        print "greater\n";
    } else {
        print "smaller\n";
    }
}

1;
```

and

`main.pl` :

```
use My::Module;
my $number = 7;
Module->print($number);
```

The problem is that when I run it I get this :

`Module
smaller`

can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the arrow operator is used, the thing on the left is implicitly passed as the first parameter.  You want to use `Module::print($number)`;

Comment: See the "Method Invocation" section in the documentation for perlobj: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Invocation

Comment: You also don't want to export `print` if you're going to call it by its fully-qualified name. And you should probably name it something else since `print` is a builtin.